# use django template with dash application

Tags: python, django, templates, embed, plotly-dash

I have set-up a dash application that works well with my django website, but I would like to have the dash application on a page that has a template.

The setup I have is the usual one, that is :

> views.py

```
def dispatcher(request):
    '''
    Main function
    @param request: Request object
    '''

    params = {
        'data': request.body,
        'method': request.method,
        'content_type': request.content_type
    }
    with server.test_request_context(request.path, **params):
        server.preprocess_request()
        try:
            response = server.full_dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            response = server.make_response(server.handle_exception(e))
        return response.get_data()

@login_required
def dash_index(request, **kwarg):

    return HttpResponse(dispatcher(request))


@csrf_exempt
def dash_ajax(request):
    return HttpResponse(dispatcher(request), content_type='application/json')
```

and

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^_dash-', views.dash_ajax),
    re_path('^', views.dash_index),
]
```

The above code works fine.
Now I've tried the following for embedding the page (view dash_index) within a template (called dashboard template). The template is not for formatting the app itself, but for elements that will be "around" the app, such as navbar, footer, menu etc.

Try n°1

```
@login_required
def dash_index(request, **kwarg):

    template_name = "dashboard_template.html"
    return HttpResponse(dispatcher(request),template_name)
```

doesn't yield error, but doesn't display template.

try n°2 :

```
@login_required
def dash_index(request, **kwarg):

    template = loader.get_template("dashboard_template.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(dispatcher(request)))
```

I get the following error from the urls.py file

```
AttributeError: module 'app_name.views' has no attribute 'dash_index'
```

Try n°3 :

```
@login_required
def dash_index(request, **kwarg):

    return render(dispatcher(request),"dashboard_template.html")
```

same error

```
AttributeError: module 'app_name.views' has no attribute 'dash_index'
```

Can sombody help ?

Answer (score 0):

You must try:-

```
return render(request, 'dashboard_template.html', context={'dash': dispatcher(request)})
```

In your `dashboard_template.html`, make sure to add safe.

```
{{ dash|safe }}
```